# The application was not started What is the issue of my code

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field emprepo in com.example.webspringproject.EmployeeRegistration required a bean of type 'com.example.employeeSetup.Repository.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.employeeSetup.Repository.EmployeeRepository' in your configuration.
```

.......................

this is my Controller

```
package com.example.webspringproject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.emailSetup.model.Employee;
import com.example.employeeSetup.Repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Controller
public class EmployeeRegistration {

    
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository emprepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/employees")
    public String employees() {
        
        return "employeeRegistation";
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/getemployee")
    public String getemployee(Employee emp) {
        
        emprepo.save(emp);
        return "Saved-Successfully";
        
    }
}
```

This is my Entity Class

```
package com.example.emailSetup.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee {
     @Id
     private int empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mobnum;
    private String address;
    private String empDept;
    private String empDesg;
    
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getMobnum() {
        return mobnum;
    }
    public void setMobnum(String mobnum) {
        this.mobnum = mobnum;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getEmpDept() {
        return empDept;
    }
    public void setEmpDept(String empDept) {
        this.empDept = empDept;
    }
    public String getEmpDesg() {
        return empDesg;
    }
    public void setEmpDesg(String empDesg) {
        this.empDesg = empDesg;
    }
    
    
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", mobnum=" + mobnum
                + ", address=" + address + ", empDept=" + empDept + ", empDesg=" + empDesg + "]";
    }
    
    
    
}
```

this is my interface....

```
package com.example.employeeSetup.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.example.emailSetup.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String>{
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you missed the @Repository annotation on EmployeeRepository.

Comment: i added @Repository annotation same problem occurs

Comment: The @Id field `empId` of your entity is of (primitive) type int, but your repository uses String. 

Change the id field in entity to Long and use `extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long>